# Pyyaml nested objects

Tags: python, pyyaml

I want to interpret following YAML string with PyYaml:

```
      - !Table
        header:
          - !Column
            - !Paragraph
              text: 'header1'
          - !Column 
            - !Paragraph
              text: 'header2'
```

I have Table and Paragraph classes that are inherited from `yaml.YAMLObject` class. But I don't know what to do about `!Column` tag? This tag should be treated only as a named array tag.

When I want to build objects from `yaml.load()` function, I got following error:

```
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor 
for the tag '!Column'
in "<unicode string>", line 19, column 17:
              - !Column
                ^
```

Comment: What is a "named array"? Do you mean named tuple? You would still need to add a constructor for that tag, and it gets a sequence (of paragraph). What would you expect as name?

Comment: @Anthon I added !Column tag in my file just for increasing readability. Named Array is wrong; I mean !Column is just a sequence that its name is for increasing readability and remarking my convention.

Comment: Please note that there was  a missing `!` before your second `Paragraph`

Comment: @Anthon my mistake. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with using `yaml.YAMLObject`:

- it is not transparent to use anything but the default `yaml.Loader` forcing you to use the unsafe `yaml.load()` which you should not do unless you have full control over the input, now and in the future.
- you cannot use it for objects that are a node consisting of a scalar or sequence. Only a mapping  can be used.

Your `!Table` and `!Paragraph` are mapping nodes. But your `!Column` is a sequence, and you explicitly need to make a constructor for that:

```
import sys
from ruamel import yaml

yaml_str = """\
- !Table
  header:
    - !Column
      - !Paragraph
        text: 'header1'
    - !Column
      - !Paragraph
        text: 'header2'

"""

class Table(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!Table'
    pass


class Paragraph(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!Paragraph'
    pass

def column_constructor(loader, node):
    return loader.construct_sequence(node)

yaml.add_constructor('!Column', column_constructor)


data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False)
```

this prints:

```
- !Table
  header:
  - - !Paragraph
      text: header1
  - - !Paragraph
      text: header2
```

and (because I use ruamel.yaml, also an `UnsafeLoaderWarning`).

If you want the output to include `!Column` then you should make a python class `Column(list)` and have `column_constructor` give back that type, and additionally write a representer for `Column` and add that to the loader.